# React native snapshot screen

Tags: react-native

I am building an app for iOS with React native and I would like to know how to take a snapshot of a given screen. I have found this [library](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) but I don't know how to use it. Does anyone know how to ?

EDIT:
I used the following code to capture a screen using the library but I get the given error.

```
try {
        captureRef(viewRef, {
        format: "jpg",
        quality: 0.8
        })
        .then(
        uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
        error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

The error

```
ReferenceError: viewRef is not defined
```

Does anybody know how to fix the error? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you have to read a little about what a `ref` is. If you are already using React hooks, check this: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

(if not, just search on how to create a ref in React with createRef)

Basically, a *ref* is something that will let you identify your component using the same variable even if the component re-renders. So, `viewRef` in your example should be a reference to a given element. Like:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  const viewRef = useRef();

  return <View ref={viewRef}>content</View>
}
```

So, your draft could be something like:

```
    import React, { useRef } from "react";
    import {Button, View, Text} from 'react-native';
    import { captureRef } from "react-native-view-shot";

    function useCapture() {
      const captureViewRef = useRef();

      function onCapture() {
        captureRef(captureViewRef, {
          format: "jpg",
          quality: 0.9
        }).then(
          uri => alert(uri), 
          error => alert("Oops, snapshot failed", error));
      }

      return {
        captureViewRef,
        onCapture
      };
    }

    function MyComponent() {
      const { captureViewRef, onCapture } = useCapture();

      return (
        <>
          <View ref={captureViewRef}><Text>content</Text></View>
          <Button title="Save" onPress={onCapture} />
        </>
      );
    }
```

As far as I know, this only generates a temporary file. If you want to see the capture saved into your device, you should use `CameraRoll` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll

I won't cover how to use it here, but it would be something like:

`CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri);` // *uri* being the path that you get from captureRef method

Just notice that your app must ask for proper permission before attempting to save to the device gallery.

Answer (score 0):

hi this can be with the help of react-native-view-shot

this is my parent component

```
                import React, {Component,useRef} from 'react';
                import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,Image,Button} from 'react-native';
                import { captureRef, captureScreen ,ViewShot} from "react-native-view-shot";
                import NewVd from './NewVd';
                import Newved from './Newved';

                export default class App extends Component {
                constructor(){
                super();
                this.state={
                    item:null,
                    captureProcessisReady:false,
                    myView:false
                };
                this.func=this.func.bind(this);
                }
                componentDidMount(){

                }
                    result1=()=>{
                                    console.log("i am here ");
                                    this.setState({captureProcessisReady:true});
                                }

                    func = (uri) => {
                                        console.log('ADD item quantity with id: ', uri);
                                        this.setState({item:uri,myView:true});
                                    };

                render() {
                    return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        {/* <NewVd  
                        func={this.func}/> */}
                        <Newved />
                        <Text>...Something to rasterize...</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
                            <Button onPress={()=>this.result1()} title="press Me"/>
                                <View>
                                {this.state.captureProcessisReady?( <NewVd func={this.func}/>):null}
                                </View>
                                <View>
                                {this.state.myView?( <Image source={{uri:this.state.item !== null?`${this.state.item}`:'https://picsum.photos/200'}} style={{width:100,height:100}} />):null}
                                </View>
                    </View>
                    );
                }
                }

                const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                container: {
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
                },
                welcome: {
                    fontSize: 20,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    margin: 10,
                },
                instructions: {
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    color: '#333333',
                    marginBottom: 5,
                },
                });
```

> this is my child component

```
       import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
    import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";


            class NewVd extends Component {
                constructor(props){
                    super(props);
                    }

                  onCapture = uri => {
                          console.log("do something with ", uri);
                          this.props.func(uri);                   //for the parent using callback
                        }


                  render() {
                            return (
                              <ViewShot onCapture={this.onCapture} captureMode="mount">
                                <Text>...Something to rasterize...</Text>
                              </ViewShot>
                            );
                          }
                        }

                  export default NewVd;
```